# How to update shield?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My shield will expire in half an hour, that means I can be attacked. How do I get shield again. Is there any other way except buying one day shield with gems. If I attack someone and win, do I get more shield? How does shield system work in general?

Answer (score 0):

You will LOSE shield time each time when you attack another Player, so NOT attacking is the best Option to keep a shield. Losin shield depends on the number of attacks, no matter if you win or lose.

Out of the [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Shields):

> If you decide to attack another player in Multiplayer battles, some shield time will be deducted. Nexting does not affect the shield time, however the more attacks you conduct under the same shield will deduct increasing amounts of shield time, conducted attacks will deduct shield time starting from 3 hours then to 4, 5, 6, 8, 10 and 12 hours.

Anyway, after you lose your shield yu get a 30 minute (or longer in higher leagues) protection ([village guard](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Village_Guard)) which will NOT reduce when you attack others.

Also clanwars do not affect you shield or protection.

---

The only ways to get a shield is being attacked and got at least 30% damage. Or, when there was a maintenace, normally you get a shield for a really short time. But this is a supercell thing. The only way you can get it fully controlled by your own is to buy it.